# Filtering a collection to a specified type generates a compiler warning

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm attempting to write a method that will take a `Collection<?>` and remove all objects that are not of type `T`, returning either the original collection or a new collection, shown in this method signature:

```
public static <T,C extends Collection<T>> C objectsOfType(Collection<?> in, Class<T> type, Class<C> collectionType);
```

For example, I have a `Collection<?>` which contains Strings, and some other objects. I want a `List<String>` from it:

```
Collection<?> allObjects = getAllObjects();
List<String> stringObjects = objectsOfType(allObjects, String.class, ArrayList.class);
```

It all works out in the end. `objectsOfType` will return `allObjects` if it is an `ArrayList` containing only `Strings`, and will otherwise create a new `ArrayList<String>` and populate it with the `String` elements of `allObjects`. I would need to add another argument to allow any `List` to be returned since `ArrayList` is more specific than necessary for the return value, because the class must have a constructor. But that's not the problem.

The problem is a compiler warning on the invocation of `objectsOfType`, and I can't figure out why:

> Type safety: Unchecked invocation
>   objectsOfType(Collection<capture#1-of ?>, Class<String>, Class<ArrayList>)
>   of the generic method objectsOfType(Collection<?>, Class<T>, Class<C>)
>   of type CollectionUtilities

What's causing this warning, and how can I fix it? As far as I can tell, everything is safe. The implementation of the method itself is not in question. That doesn't raise any warnings. Only its invocation is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList.class` is not assignable to `Class<C>`, i.e., `Class<List<String>>` in a strict/checked context, so passing this argument requires an unchecked assignment, hence the warning.  The type of `ArrayList.class` is simply `Class<ArrayList>`, where `ArrayList` is a raw type.  There is no way to use the `.class` operator to specify the class `ArrayList<String>`.

Do you really need the `Class<C>` argument in the signature?  What if you replaced it with a factory callback (e.g., something like Java 8's `Supplier<C>`)?

Alternatively, just return a `List<T>` (and use the same `List` implementation in all cases), simplifying your signature in the process:

```
public static <T> List<T> objectsOfType(Collection<?> in, Class<T> type);
```

You could also drop the wildcard and let the compiler infer the source item type:

```
public static <T, R> List<R> objectsOfType(Collection<T> in, Class<R> type);
```

Note, however, that both of the above are lax with respect to the input collection type (which you may have intended).  If you want to be strict, you could limit the input item type to a superclass of the result type:

```
public static <T> List<T> objectsOfType(Collection<? super T> in, Class<T> type);
```

Comment: I suppose I don't foresee a need to return something other than a List right now. I may be making it a bit *too* generic.

Comment: In general, I would have filter methods like this return an unmodifiable list anyway.

Comment: One possible small improvement: restrict the type of the input collection to `Collection<? extends T>`. Otherwise you can do things like `objectsOfType(listOfIntegers, String.class)`, which works but will always return nothing (since no Integer can be a String). Obviously not if you need to be able to pass in an unknown collection (which it seems may be the case in the question).

Comment: I'm trying to allow a collection which may contain objects of type T *as well as* other objects, and only return those of type T, so that wouldn't really work.

Comment: Right, I assumed you wanted to select only those items of type `T` and filter out the others.  Perhaps @andersschuller meant `Collection<? super T>`?